# Powershell string work

Tags: string, powershell, copy, ls, dir

This is my first question here and i'm new to powershell.

I have a folder `$home\Devoluciones\` with several files named DtoXXXYYYYMM.dat where XXX is a company number, YYYY is the current year and MM stands for current month.

What i need to do is to copy those files to folders named with the company number, for example if i have Dto509201506.dat and Dto908201506.dat i need to copy those files to `$destination\509\` and `$destination\908\` respectively.

Till now i have the following code:

```psh
#List the items and send to a.txt
ls $home\Devoluciones\Dto*.dat | select -exp Name > $home\a.txt
#From a.txt keep first 6 characters and send to b.txt
Get-Content $home\a.txt | foreach {$_.remove(6)} | Add-Content $home\b.txt
#From b.txt replace Dto with "" and send to c.txt
Get-Content $home\b.txt | foreach {$_ -replace "Dto",""} | Add-Content $home\c.txt
#From c.txt copy the files to destination
Get-Content $home\c.txt | foreach {copy-item $home\Devoluciones\*$_*.dat $Destination\$_\}
#Clean temp files
Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore $home\a.txt -Force
Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore $home\b.txt -Force
Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore $home\c.txt -Force
```

I would like to achieve the same result doing it "cleaner" than this, i want to learn how to manipulate the string in one line and if is it possible copy all with only one command.

Thanks, Nestor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation that should be self explanatory. I'm sure somebody will add a more concise one line answer as well.

```psh
$Files = Get-Childitem -path "$home\Devoluciones\*" -include *.dat
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $company = $file.Name.Substring(3,3)
    copy-item $file.FullName (join-path (join-path $Destination $company) $file.Name)
}
```

EDIT: Fixed error in destination path

EDIT2: [Get-ChildItem](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849800.aspx) *"The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the Recurse parameter or the path leads to the contents of a directory, such as C:\Windows*, where the wildcard character is specified"*

Comment: I think the double quotes have to be single quotes.  Otherwise $home will be misinterpred as the name of a variable.

Comment: @WalterMitty that is possible but I think in this case we are using the `$home` variable. We want that to expand.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the edit. Does *<!-- language: lang-psh -->* do the syntax highlight for PowerShell?

Comment: Yes and `<!-- language: lang-powershell -->` but psh is shorter :)

Comment: ok.  I failed to get that $home was intended as a variable reference.

Comment: I like this, i'm gonna try it tomorrow.

Comment: This isn't working for me.
I would like to understand how this work to find a workaround:
You define $Files as a group of files.
Then you do foreach ($file in $files)
1) Why you use $files instead of $Files? Ps variables are not case sensitive?

I added inside the foreach this code to see what's happening:
Write-Host $company
Write-Host $file.FullName

But it isn't writing anythig.
2) What i have to do to write thses variable content into screen?

Comment: @Nestoter Yes, PS variable names are not case sensitive, but it's good practice to use the same case all the time. My bad. Write-Host is the right command, so if you are not getting results, it's most likely that you are not getting any files in. Try just a simple `$Files = Get-Childitem -path "a known directory here ..."`. See if that can get some results.

Comment: @JanChrbolka
It worked after remove -include *.dat
Thank you Jan!

Answer (score 1):

All PowerShell can be written as one awful line if you want it to be but here is something that is quite terse.

```psh
$path = "$home\Devoluciones\"
$destination = "C:\temp"
Get-ChildItem "$path\dto*.dat" | Copy-Item  -Destination {[System.IO.Path]::Combine($destination,($_.Name).Substring(3,3),$_.Name)} -Force
```

What this will do here is exactly what you want. Take all the filtered files and for each one copy it to the folder that corresponds with the 3-6th letter code contained within. If the destination folder does not exist then we use `-Force` to make it. Helpful for new company codes. We use `[System.IO.Path]::Combine` to make the target file path which consists of the destination folder, company folder and current file in the pipe.